# "Too early" early stopping in Keras

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I'm training a neural network with Keras, using early stopping. However, when training, the network very early hits a point where the validation loss is unnaturally low, which flattens out after a while, like this.
[image: loss functions]

When using early stopping with `patience = 50` the validation loss flattens out, but never goes below the validation loss in the beginning.

I've trained the network multiple times with the same result, with both the rmsprop (with learning rates from 0.1 to 1e-4) and adam optimizers.

Does anyone know if there is a way to set a "burn in period" (like in a Markov Chain Monte Carlo model) for the network, before monitoring the validation loss for choosing the best model?

Comment: you can do it with customized callback, by setting a method in the callback: `on_train_epoch_end` or `on_train_batch_end` e.g. and putting a condition `if epoch >= N:` in fron of all the things it should do. While `N` will be the "burn in period" number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe I'm 2/3 years late, but I had the same issue, and I've solved coding this callback:

```py
class DelayedEarlyStopping(tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping):
    def __init__(self, burn_in, **kwargs):
        super(DelayedEarlyStopping, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.burn_in = burn_in

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if epoch >= self.burn_in:
            super().on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
        else:
            super().on_train_begin(logs=None)

early_stopping_monitor = DelayedEarlyStopping(
    100,
    monitor='val_total_loss',
    min_delta=0,
    patience=20,
    verbose=0,
    mode='auto',
    baseline=40,
    restore_best_weights=True
)
```